# Can our badges be some symbol that's more recognizable than just featureless hexagons?

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-interface, site-design

Sci-fi's stack Badge is the rebel alliance symbol, some other stacks have other cool symbols that represent their badges. As is right now, we have dice that well... don't really look like dice.

They kind of just look like Hexagons. Regular normal hexagons.

[image: a screenshot of hexagon badges]

I propose we find a way to make them look more like dice, or change them to swords, staves, daggers, or something more fantasy-like. I'd like them to be swords, but I have created some alternatives for those who still like dice.

It's been a while since this was looked over, does anyone still think that the badge icons should be changed?

Comment: never even realized they were supposed to be dice...

Comment: Ha, I always thought they were coins (gp, sp, cp — my D&D roots are showing).

Comment: I didn't even notice they weren't circles until you pointed it out.

Comment: I thought they were circular coins. In this post, when you said they were dice, I thought they were d6's at an angle.

Comment: I'm all for it--have already upvoted your work below.

Comment: any movement on this? what would a next step be?

Comment: I was playing war games/board games long before D&D or any RPG.  The Hexagons on Avalon Hill games is sacred!  Be proud of your fearless, uh, sorry, featureless, hexagons!  :)

Answer (score 18):

I like the dice badges, and I appreciate their minimalistic design: they're dice if you look (the RPG.SE banner d20 is right there for the comparison) but they don't call attention to themselves. I think it's totally fine that they aren't obviously RPG-related symbols. It's not like [english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com)'s badges are iconic of their topic, and they look great!

Still, making the badges more immediately recognisable as dice could be nice if they don't get too flash in the process. The trick is, badges are an ubiquitous part of the site design and shouldn't be overly complex or they clutter up every page they're on. Maybe a d6 with transparent pixels for the pips, similar to [movies.se](http://movies.stackexchange.com)'s film-reel badge?

I'm firmly against a more "fantasy-like" design for the badges, though. Polyhedral dice are universally recognised in the RPG community as emblematic of our hobby; fantasy visuals represent only a portion of the hobby's subjects while also evoking other mediums which use those visuals too. A sword or dagger or staff doesn't say "role-playing game" to me, any more than a laser rifle or a shoggoth does. (I feel the scifi Stack's choice to draw on a single franchise for its badge design is a little tone-deaf, actually.)

Comment: I like your idea of using transparency so that they remain single-colored. What if we kept them exactly as they currently are, but add lines for each edge in transparent, as opposed to black or white? I don't know if the badge icons are in a format that supports alpha channel, but if they are, that might be ideal for the small resolution.

Comment: @DanHenderson The sprite sheet is a PNG with transparency, yes.

Comment: +1 for keeping it away from fantasy-centric

Comment: The d6 is also reminiscent of board games and gambling. Given the choice of any of the standard polyhedrals, I'd prefer the d20, even if it's only actually connected to one game franchise which I don't even play. It's the most recognisable polyhedral.

Comment: +1 for minimalism and elegance. I like our "regular normal hexagons" far better than the [weird squiggles](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) or [funny headgear](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) that some of the newer sites have ended up with.

Answer (score 13):

**Make the Badge icons we already have even better.**

I've taken the liberty of creating a few mockups of possible badge designs that keep to the dice format while maintaining its linework at lower resolutions, as well as a badge edit of the favicon:

[image: Dice Mockup White BG]

[image: Dice Mockup Saturated]

[image: Dice Mockup Black BG]

[image: Dice Favicon Mockup]

Here's also some mockups provided by @MrLemon after taking the available sprite sheet and encoding it into a website via developer tools:

[image: Top Toolbar mockup]

[image: Answer/Edit bar mockup]

As you can see the dice lines are all still visible when spliced into the page code, and are very recognizable polyhedrons compared to our current badges.

The end sprite sheet can be found here:
[image]

Comment: I like the idea here, but these iterations feel cluttered and overcomplicated (lots of little lines, and each line changes its width along its length) for the simple idea they're conveying and their ever-present role in the site design. If I get a chance over the next week I'll try my hand at some variations myself.

Comment: personally, I like the third line the best; thanks for the work

Comment: Any chance it'd be easy for you to show us what they look like with one vertex top-center, so as to sit in the same alignment as the site logo?

Comment: These are about twice the resolution of the current versions, and I don't think the fine details would scale back down well. You might want to start mockups from the [actual sprite sheet's badges](http://cdn.sstatic.net/rpg/img/sprites.png?v=09dd20096a5f) to ensure the details fit in the available pixel real estate.

Comment: Looking at the HTML element in the header, it looks like you’ve got about 12px square to work with.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie There's a fair amount of empty space to accommodate the size of those badges that is mostly transparency, if you compare it to Sci-fi stack it's about 20x20px

Comment: It's true, but fitting them onto the sheet means they're tested for fit already and nobody voting has to guess if the designs actually work.

Comment: If I made the lines on the D20 thicker I could probably keep the look at 12x12 but I think even with something like 16x16 it'd be save and still recognizable. Is there a way to run tests?

Comment: Yes. [Your browser's built-in dev tools](http://support.kissmetrics.com/getting-started/testing-km/using-dev-tools.html) will let you [change an image just for yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954564/swapping-an-image-during-web-development), and aren't hard to use for just that if you have some time on hand to fiddle with and figure them out.

Comment: I just made [this](http://i.imgur.com/dfJLjSi.png).

Comment: My take is "don't try to fix what isn't broken."

Comment: @Sandwich When I sub that into the stylesheet, [this is what happens](http://i.stack.imgur.com/To543.png). It looks like it's giving the image max 15×15px, and even that runs into the numbers. I get the same result using it on SF/F. Looking at their sprite sheet, even their seemingly-huge badges are only 14×14px, so I think that's the max size the CSS is designed to use. (Our badge images are currently 10×11px.)

Comment: Alright, I'll lower the resolution then.

Comment: Here's a lower resolution (The D20's are slightly larger than our current badges) [here](http://i.imgur.com/y8Kp0YA.png)

Comment: Does that one work @SevenSidedDie?

Comment: @Sandwich I moved the icons a few pixels and it seems to work with [these](http://i.imgur.com/EcIBSF6.png), after setting the size to 14x14. It does highlight some issue with the position of the badges in the title-bar, they are much lower there compared to their position in the nameplate below a post.

Comment: @MrLemon That's good then. Do you have a screenshot showing the change?

Comment: @Sandwich Uh... of course: [Nameplate](http://i.imgur.com/e2lM2hC.png) and [Title Bar](http://i.imgur.com/sfRDAID.png)

Comment: @MrLemon Ah that looks nice.

Comment: I like the styling of the white lines in the solid color, but I thought you were going to add 3 light lines to make them d6s viewed at an angle, not d20s. That would result in less clutter, if nothing else.

Comment: I don't think that'd be as good as d20's, the d20's are kind of the symbol of the stack.

Answer (score 11):

While they are dice, if we're going to change them, we might pick different types of dice for the different badges. A triangle (four sided die), a square (six sided die) and an octagon (12 sided die) for example could work.

They are still quite minimal (just basic shapes) but I think most RPG'ers would recognize them for what they are (more easily than the current ones), especially if you order them from smallest number of sides to biggest.

As an aside, it also removes us a bit from using only the 20-sided die, because like the argument "a sword does not represent all roleplaying" one can also say "a 20-sided die does not represent all roleplaying). I understand that funny dice are often involved, but still moving away from using only the one made big by D&D might also be a good thing.

Comment: Of course, hexagonal grids fit a lot of games ... :-)

Comment: I like the idea ([graphicdesign.se] has a very similar conceit), but no octagons please. If folks thought a *six*-sided polygon was a circle, eight sides won't fare better.

Comment: +1 for getting away from all-d20 iconography. But I don't envy the task of trying to come up with a 16x16 pixel inclusive representation....